# Problem with format of date datePicker Symfony 4

Tags: jquery, symfony, datepicker

I have issue with date time picker in symfony 4. I need view date in format example 29.8.2019

jQuery:

```
$('#customer_date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  altFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  altField: "#customer_date"

  });
```

FormType:

```
->add('date',DateType::class,[
    'label' => 'Date:',
    'html5' => false,
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

If i pick some date: This value is not valid.  "13.09.2019"

Answer (score 0):

DateFormat in datepicker is other than format in DateType. Add the same format in this two places. From symfony 4.3 there is a new attribute "input_value". Maybe try add this attribute.